# Perfect way to make a header

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I am creating a web application in Laravel and I have a template for the header element. What I want to do is make the header fixed on the top. I have the following code to do it:

```
    .header{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
    font-family: "Viga";
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
   }
```

But, the header appears some way down from the page and my margin-top to other elements aren't working as well. So, how do I make the header fixed at the top and still have all other styling working? Thanks

Comment: have you tried `top: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: @Ali That does hide that annoying gap but margins are not working and everything is glued to the header. How do I avoid that?

Comment: add a `padding-top` to your `body` with the size of your header height

Comment: @Ali That just messed everything. How do I avoid scrolls in my whole page. I am getting scrolls when I mention `padding-top` in the body.

Comment: @PHPCoder it may not be a good idea to have a percentage based height for your header. The height will change depending on screen size rather than content, which can give an unintended result on some screens. Leave the height blank (or set to auto) to fit to its content, or set it with fixed units such as `px` so you have consistent behaviour across all screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give the height for a fixed element, overlapping issues might be arise, for such cases repel the rest of the content from the header.

i.e., here the height of the header is `50px` so repel it from the content by giving `margin-top:50px;` to the content.

When you use `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` use `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` to mention its position where you want it to be

Try this

```css
    .header{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        /*padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;*/
        font-family: "Viga";
        border: none;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
       }
       
    body{background:red; height:7000px;}
    .content{color:#fff; margin-top:50px;}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
 <p>Header lays here!</p>
 </header>
 <div class="content">
 <h1>Content heading</h1>
 <p>content content content content content content contentcontentcontentcontent contentcontent content content content content content content content</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Everything worked fine but the header is overlapping some of my other contents, how do I deal with that?

Comment: can u add a screenshot of the problem

Comment: Thanks! And I didn't find a way to insert pictures!

Comment: When I set the margin in another div, the width of the header increases itself and scroll appears in the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183476/discussion-between-viira-and-phpcoder).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background-color: #7e797b;
    }
.header{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em;
    font-family: "Viga";
    border: none;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0
   }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
 <header class="header">  
    <h1>Header</h1>
 </header>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Just add left:0 and top:0. No need to give the height of the header, as the height will change according to the screen height.